# Problem with column transformations inside pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to build a pipeline containing several user-defined column
transformations. When creating a new column transformer, I'm inheriting
`sklearn.base.BaseEstimator` and `sklearn.base.TransformerMixin`, and
implementing `fit` and `transform` methods. Calling the transformations 
directly works as expected, but using them as a part of a 
`sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` instance fails giving ambiguous errors.

Let's say I have a `pandas.DataFrame` instance `df` containing the following data:

```py
       date   genre
0   9/22/11  horror
1   1/16/04    NULL
2  10/11/96    NULL
3   3/28/13   drama
4   4/22/94   drama
```

I want to implement two transformers:

1. `DateTransformer`, which converts date strings in `df['date']`
   into a `numpy.array` instance containing year, month, and day for every row.
2. `GenreTransformer`, which for every genre in `df['genre']`, returns 1 if
   it is not specified ('NULL'), and -1 otherwise.

Here is my code:

```py
class GenreTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, x):
        x_copy = x.copy()
        x_copy[x_copy != 'NULL'] = -1
        x_copy[x_copy == 'NULL'] = 1
        return x_copy.values

class DateTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, x):
        x_timestamp = x.apply(pd.to_datetime)
        return np.column_stack((
            x_timestamp.apply(lambda t: t.year).values,
            x_timestamp.apply(lambda t: t.month).values,
            x_timestamp.apply(lambda t: t.day).values,
        ))
```

Both transformers work correctly:

```py
>>> GenreTransformer().fit_transform(df['genre'])
array([-1, 1, 1, -1, -1])

>>> DateTransformer().fit_transform(df['date'])
array([[2011,    9,   22],
       [2004,    1,   16],
       [1996,   10,   11],
       [2013,    3,   28],
       [1994,    4,   22]])
```

However, when I merge the transformers using
`sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer`, and create a pipeline,
`DateTransformer` doesn't work:

```py
column_transformer = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('date_trans', DateTransformer(), ['date']),
        ('genre_trans', GenreTransformer(), ['genre']),
    ],
    remainder='drop',
)

pipe = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('union', column_transformer),
        # estimators
    ],
)
```

```py
>>> pipe.fit(df)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last)
...
AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'year'", 'occurred at index date')
```

Interestingly, using `pandas.Series.apply` instead
of mask methods inside `GenreTransformer.transform` and fitting the pipe also 
fails:

```py
class GenreTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    # ...
    def transform(self, x):
        return x.apply(lambda g: -1 if g != 'NULL' else 1)
```

```py
>>> pipe.fit(df)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last)
...
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index genre')
```

So, I guess there is something wrong with applying `pandas.Series.apply` method
inside pipelines. Is there a possibility of a bug on scikit-learn source code?
Or there is something I'm doing incorrectly? If so, can you please point out
how to implement column transformers, so that I can include them in pipelines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a subtle mistake in your code.

You specified `['date']` for the columns to apply `DateTransformer` to. When you do so, [it signifies that `DateTransformer` expects a 2D array-like], which, in this case, is a `DataFrame`. However, it actually expects a 1D array-like, or a `Series`.

Therefore, what you did was equivalent to `DateTransformer().fit_transform(df[['date']])`, when you actually wanted `df['date']`.

Accordingly, pass `('date_trans', DateTransformer(), 'date')` to `ColumnTransformer` instead and everything should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, @gmds. Should have paid closer attention to the conventions of sklearn transformers. According to the documentation, `TransformerMixin.fit_transform` method both accepts and returns 2D array-like. So, it is more convenient to pass list of columns into column transformers. Nonetheless, when I build a new transformer accepting data of shape `(x.shape[0], 1)` and return transformed 2D numpy array of the same shape, I again get an error.

Comment: @SanjarAdylov Yup, but `ColumnTransformer` wraps it, so you need not necessarily follow the `TransformerMixin` convention. Anyway, I'm not really sure what you mean; have you tried my suggested solution? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, @gmds, your solution works well. But actually, I have some other transformers that are expected to return 1D array-like: `transform` accepts `pandas.Series` instance `x` and returns `x.apply(my_func)`. After pipeline fitting, `ValueError` is raised: `The output of the transformer should be 2D (scipy matrix, array, or pandas DataFrame)`. I then reshape the result so that the transformed `x` is of the shape `(x.shape[0], 1)` but it still raises an error.

Comment: @SanjarAdylov That is a problem. However, to help you, we would need an actual example (since it seems the problem you actually brought up in your question has been solved). Accordingly, I suggest either editing your question or asking a new question.

Comment: I have come up with a solution. The issue was related rather to the estimators inside the pipeline (my code was buggy). Thanks again, @gmds!

Comment: @SanjarAdylov Could you please share the solution? You said your code was buggy, so how did you fix? please help here with your correct code, I'm also having similar requirement.